# Export XCode 6 project to SVN repository

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, svn, xcode6

Everywhere I search, I get half the solution for exporting Xcode project on Subversion. And for Xcode6, I am not able to find any reliable link.

I have created an iOS project on Xcode6. And now I want to export it to Subversion. The server admin has created my credentials and I have them along with server url. He has created a blank repository on the server too. I have created Repository from **Xcode -> Preferences -> Add Repository**. But that's all. I am not able to proceed further.

How should I export the project from Xcode6 to SVN?

Comment: Tagging iOS, iPhone as not getting views from just Xcode tag.

Comment: make sure that you update Command Line Tools.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to do this via the terminal.

1. Close Xcode
2. Go to the project's folder in the Terminal (`cd path/to/project`)
3. Use the `svn import`command:

   ```
   svn import -m "New Import"  MyProject/ https://myserver.me.com/svn/trunk/MyProject
   ```
4. And finally checkout the project using

   ```
   svn co https://myserver.me.com/svn/trunk/MyProject
   ```

Comment: That is really easy. I don't know why it is confusing to do that from XCode. Thanks :)

Comment: No problems. Agreed, Xcode's version control management is really confusing.

Comment: Wow, I have been working on this issue for more than 3 hours, trying to figure how to do that from XCode, but apparently command line is the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. First Go to **Preferences -> Accounts.**
2. Click on **"+"** then **Add Repository.**
3. Add your Credentials.
4. It will Validate.

Once its Authenticated Or Validated Go to **Source Control**

1. Click on **Create Working Copy / Copies.**
2. It will make Working Copy For you.
3. Then after that **Commit** Button will be now clickable.
4. Click on **Commit**.

**And Here We Go**

Your Code will start to upload on the validated repo.